# invoke-command with a parameter accessing UNC

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to generate some IDs using a adobe tool called adobe-licensing-toolkit.exe.
I need to run the command remotely in 100 computers.
Executing the command manually works flawless

```
C:\temp\adobe-licensing-toolkit.exe -c -f \\XXXXXXX\c$\temp\IDs.csv
Adobe Licensing Toolkit (1.1.0.98)
Operation Successfully Completed
```

Now I tried to replicate that using remote PS without success. I think it is a matter of parameters.

The following command ends correctly but it generates the file locally in the remote computer.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {  param($whatToDo,$targetCSV) &('C:\TEMP\adobe-licensing-toolkit.exe') --$whatToDo --$targetCSV "C:\temp\ID.csv"} -ArgumentList "generateChallengeKey","filepath"
```

If I try to use the UNC in the parameter, the result is Operation failed.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {  param($whatToDo,$targetCSV) &('\\XXXXXXXX\c$\TEMP\adobe-licensing-toolkit.exe') --$whatToDo --$targetCSV "C:\temp\ID.csv"} -ArgumentList "generateChallengeKey","filepath"
```

I also tried to add path in the parameter. In that case is powershell who complains.

```
 Invoke-Command -Session $Server01 -ScriptBlock {  param($whatToDo,$targetCSV) &('C:\TEMP\FRL\adobe-licensing-toolkit.exe') --$whatToDo --$targetCSV } -ArgumentList @("generateChallengeKey","filepath \\XXXXXXX\c$\temp\ID.csv")

unknown option -- filepath \\XXXXX\c$\temp\ID.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (unknown option ...c$\temp\ID.csv:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : XXXXXXX
```

I have the feeling that the issue is in the way parameter is passed but I haven't managed to find the solution.

The exe file is already present in all target computers.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need the param block, but it doesn't matter here. Never done an adobe toolkit installation, but why are you using a single hyphen in the very first example, and not the ones remotely? Can you try to include the hyphens with the arguments themselves? I.e: `-ArgumentList @("-generateChallengeKey"...`

Comment: Looks like double hop issue - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.1. It needs credentials to use that unc path.

Answer (score 0):

I would presume you have toolkit present in all remote computer in path: "C:\TEMP\adobe-licensing-toolkit.exe". You can simply use

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock { & "C:\TEMP\adobe-licensing-toolkit.exe" -c -f \\XXXXX\$env:Computername-IDs.csv}

Adding $env:Computername in share path would generate unique file for each computer.